# Drivers for HP deskjet 2545 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing, hp

Are there any drivers for HP deskjet 2545 for Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried HPLIP Toolbox?. Please see [this](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/deskjet/deskjet_d2500_series.html) link. HP Deskjet d2545 Printer is listed there. You can [install](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/hplip/) via software centre. Latest version is available [here.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/)